# How do you configure SSO to SharePoint from an iPad?

Tags: sharepoint, isa-server, ipad

I've been asked to look at implementing SSO from an iPad to a SharePoint 2007 installation.

This could use ISA Server 2006 or any other product.

Is this possible? If so how?

I was thinking installing client certificates on an iPad, using them on the ISA Server, and then passing the credentials of that user through to SharePoint?

Comment: Do you mean you need the iPad to access the ShaePoint site without having to enter the credentials in Safari? As it does with IE on a domain based PC? Or are you talking about SSO in another sens, such as when web applications need to access resources from non-SharePoint systems such as an ERP system?

Comment: The first one. So some sort of integrated authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Microsoft Forefront UAG](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/unified-access-gateway/en/us/). The 2007 version works with my iPhone and the 2010 version is supposedly more "Mac Friendly".